# Importing data to SQL from Excel using Talend

Tags: talend

I am trying to import data to SQL from Excel. I have created a successful connection with the database but while trying to retrieve the schema I am not getting my table, instead I am having the schema of the database (Type CATALOG).

How do I get the schema of the table to which I will export the Excel data?

I have refereed to this video to do the import.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDBYU9f1p-I

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job? Maybe include the txxxSQLInput configuration as well?

Comment: I have not used txxxSQLInput, just following the steps provided in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can use is [tFileExcelSheetOutput](http://www.talendforge.org/exchange/?eid=624&product=tos&action=view&nav=1,1,1), map what you need with tMap and send the to t[DB]Input.

[image]

http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-tdbinput-reference.html

Comment: Thanks.I just needed to expand the database that I was getting. Inside it there was the table which I needed.