# Transferring data from Excel file (multiple sheets) to SQL (multiple tables) in a step by step process

Tags: sql, excel, etl, talend

**Talend**

I want to transfer data from Excel to SQL. My Excel worksheet has 20 different sheets having data to be copied in 20 different tables.
I want to create a single job to perform this task in a step by step manner.

My tables have dependencies so it is very important to copy data to these tables in a specific order.
I want to have 20 steps in a single job.

Any help (online source / video) regarding how to go about this task would be appreciated.

I am thinking about using trigger -> OncomponentOk for this task. I will connect 1st output with second input using this. And so on.. I believe that this will work but after transferring the data in to the last table I want to call a stored procedure and I am unsure about how to do it. Let me know if you any idea about this

Comment: Is this a one time and throw away or something that would get repeated on a re-occurring basis? and and what flavor of SQL? MSFT, Oracle, DB2, mySQL what and version?

Comment: It would be one time only.
I am using SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: For this type of process, I often create linked tables in Access that link to the SQL server tables. Then copy and paste from Excel into Access. Takes some work, but honestly it would take more work to write something custom for only 20 tables...

Comment: Later on as my project will expand I would have to work with large number of table entries.
I had to use Excel to use macros so that I can define the number of records I want to generate at a particular time.

Comment: I am thinking about using trigger -> OncomponentOk for this task. I will connect 1st output with second input using this. And so on..

I believe that this will work but after transferring the data in to the last table I want to call a stored procedure and I am unsure about how to do it.
Let me know if you any idea about this.

Comment: I still have to try with the call to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

you have to design job like below to solve this issue.

```
openDbconnection---oncomponentOk----tFileInputExcel(sheet 1)------tSQlOuput
```

and add rest of sub jobs after previous using subjobok link. 
refer image for more details. \

[image]

Comment: in adition to your answer, [here is a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833391/importing-data-to-sql-from-excel-using-talend/23837687#23837687) with a talend screenshot solving Excel -> DB

Comment: Can you tell me how can I remove already existing entries in SQL server table?

I want to copy data from Excel to SQL server table but need to delete already existing table entries in table, each time before copying from Excel.

Comment: I used the stored procedure and did it. Thanks.

Comment: [There a proposal for a dedicated Q&A site for Business Intelligence. Follow, Post and Support to get it up.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)